How to get store a changing signal value in a java variable using the VEGA API?
I embedded my vega visualisation into html and want to use some variables as inputs for further javascript specifications.
How can I bind a javascript variable to a VEGA signal which can change depending on my interaction with the visualisation? I want the variable to change online with the changing VEGA signal. Is this possible?
I am able to see my variables in the console using the signal listener:
    view.addSignalListener('num_points', function(name, value) {
                    points = value ;
                    console.log(points)
                    console.log(name + ': ' + value);
                    document.getElementById("demo").textContent = points;
                    });

I thought the easiest way is to simply bind the variable to an Element (here called "demo") and access the value for later purpose. However, even though when changing the variable the text content of the element is changing correctly, fetching the text content for later purposes remains with the initial value thus does not get updated. I also tried using view.signal('name'), however, it does not do anything for me.

Use Vega View API's addSignalListener to listen for changes to signal and update a variable accordingly:
let points:
const view = new vega.View(vega.parse(yourVegaSpec))
  .renderer('canvas')
  .initialize('#view')
  .hover()
  .run();
view.addSignalListener('num_points', function(name, value) {
  points = value;
  console.log(points);
  console.log(name + ': ' + value);
  document.getElementById("demo").textContent = points;
});


this is not working for me. the points variable is only defined within the function. If I access is outside the addSignalListener method, points is undefined

@Butters Your issue is due to the asynchronous nature of JavaScript. The addSignalListener function sets up a listener that will update the points when the 'num_points' signal changes, but this happens asynchronously. The rest of your code continues to run before the listener has a chance to update. If you try to access points immediately after setting up the listener, it will still be undefined because the listener hasn't had a chance to update it yet.

@Butters To work, you need to ensure that any code that depends on the value of points is run after it has been updated. You can do this by putting that code inside the listener function, or by using another function that gets called when the value changes.
